# How to integrate NUnit Tests (written in C#) in TFS builds?

Tags: automation, automated-tests, nunit, integration, tfsbuild

I've written tests using Selenium in NUnit Framework using C# language. I want to associate these tests as part of builds in the TFS. So whenever new build is generated. These tests would be able to run as part of builds and generate/email reports as well.

Comment: Which tfs build are you using? The old xmal build or the new vnext build?

Comment: I'm using TFS build 2015

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recommend you to use the new build system vNext build. vNext builds are JSON based, and you can plugin tasks built in msbuild, powershell and varied other scripting languages.

About how to integrate NUnit Tests in TFS builds, this blog describes clearly how to do this: [Running NUnit Tests in a TFS 2015 Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/03/16/running-nunit-tests-in-a-tfs-2015-build-vnext/)

> Simply summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Add Nuget Package for NUnit Test Adapter
> 2. Specify path of custom Test Adapter inside build definition
>
>    - Copying adapters inside Visual Studio TestWindows folder
>    - Specify Path to Custom Test Adapter with nunit packages

Some other tutorial for you reference:

[xUnit or NUnit with Visual Studio Online Build](http://nocture.dk/2015/06/19/xunit-or-nunit-with-visual-studio-online-build/)

[Running nUnit and Jasmine.JS unit tests in TFS/VSO vNext build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-gb/docs/test/continuous-testing/test-build)

Comment: Thanks for the answer